# Paraview: Accessing Timeseries Min/Max in python

Tags: python, paraview

I'm attempting to export a set of camera perspective views of a timeseries, and I would like to be able to set RescaleTransferFunction to global min/max of the timeseries. I haven't been able to find a way to access these min/max without iterating over each timestep and comparing them all.

Is there a better method to doing this? When I record a trace paraview seems to magically just have the values.

```
# Set up the Color map
lut_rdr = lookuptable.vtkPVLUTReader()
arr = model.PointData.GetArray('Temperature_(K)')  # only gives the range for the current timestep
rng = arr.GetRange()
lut = lut_rdr.GetLUT(arr, 'Grayscale')
lut.RescaleTransferFunction(rng[0], rng[1])

dp.ColorArrayName = 'Temperature_(K)'
dp.LookupTable = lut

Render()
```

Comment: There is not a convenient way to get the data range over all time steps, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!